# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column using join

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve the values based on the user's selected that I joined using `first` method. But when I tried to put the values in my form. It says

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sent_document_user.document.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `documents`.`title`, `categories`.`category_type`, `documents`.`content`, `documents`.`id` from `sent_document_user` inner join `documents` on `documents`.`id` = `sent_document_user`.`document`.`id` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `documents`.`category_id` where `documents`.`id` = 241 limit 1)``

I joined it properly I don't know why I can't retrieve the values that I selected. This is my code in SQL that works well.

```
SELECT D.title, C.category_type, D.content, D.id FROM sent_document_user SD
INNER JOIN documents D ON SD.document_id = D.id
INNER JOIN categories C ON D.category_id = C.id;
```

**Controller**

```
public function readSentDocuments($id)
{
  $documentLists = DB::table('sent_document_user')->select('documents.title', 'categories.category_type', 'documents.content', 'documents.id')
    ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'sent_document_user.document.id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
    ->where('documents.id', '=', $id)->first();

   return view ('document.readSent')->with('documentLists', $documentLists);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class = "form-group">

                    <label for = "title" class = "control-label">Title:</label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "title" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $documentLists->title }}">

                </div>

                <div class = "form-group">

                    <label for = "category" class = "control-label">Category:</label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "category" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $documentLists->category_type }}">

                </div>

                <div class = "form-group">

                    <textarea id = "content">{{ $documentLists->content }}</textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: How can you use `sent_document_user.document.id `. Did you mean `sent_document_user.document`  in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an incorrect column name

```
 ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'sent_document_user.document.id')
```

Try **sent_document_user.document_id** instead of **sent_document_user.document.id**

Answer (score 3):

Typo:

```
->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'sent_document_user.document.id')
                                                               here--^
```

Since that's a `.`, the DB server is interpreting it as `dbname.tablename.fieldname`, and you don't have a database named `sent_document_user`.